# How to delete numbers and date time after phrase using sed command?

Tags: regex, sed

Following syntax delete everything after specific phrase:

```
s/\(.*\Build ID:.\).*/\1/g
s/\(.*\Build Date:.\).*/\1/g
```

However I need to secure this part of code and to delete:

- only 8 digits number date time after specific phrase
- only date time (YYYY-MM-DD space HH:MM:SS) after specific phrase

Input:

```
Build ID: 14257823
Build Date: 2019-06-27 03:09:33
```

Output:

```
Build ID:
Build Date:
```

To cut only 8-digits and time stamp please use:

`s/[0-9]\{8\}//g
s/[0-9]\{4\}\-[0-9]\{2\}\-[0-9]\{2\} [0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}//g`

Comment: What exactly do you want to consider as a "date time" ? Presumably, `"today"` is not a date, but can you rely on **exactly** YYYY-MM-DD space HH:MM:SS ? Never milliseconds, always seconds etc ?

Comment: Maybe `sed -E 's/(.*Build ID:.)[0-9]{8}$/\1/g; s/(.*Build Date:.)[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/\1/g' file`  will suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use character classes and repetition quantifier.

The build id format in your example is `[0-9]\{8\}` (the character class takes all digits and repeats them 8 times) and the date format is `[0-9]\{4\}\-[0-9]\{2\}\-[0-9]\{2\} [0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}`:

- four digits
- hyphen
- two digits
- hyphen
- two digits
- space
- two digits
- colon
- two digits
- colon
- two digits

This gives the following regexes

```
s/\(.*Build ID:.\)[0-9]\{8\}/\1/g
s/\(.*Build Date:.\)[0-9]\{4\}\-[0-9]\{2\}\-[0-9]\{2\} [0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}/\1/g
```

Comment: `s/\(.*\Build ID:.\)[0-9]\{8\}/\1/g` will also match a part of `Build ID: 123456789098765`, same issue is with the second command.

Comment: ITYM `.*Build` instead of `.*\Build` and `-` instead of `\-`. Escaping literal chars just obfuscates the code at best and sometimes can turn those literal chars into meta-chars.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I missed that